# Thumbnails are Not Displayed in SharePoint 2010 Picture Library

Tags: picture-library

I have created a Picture Library in SharePoint 2010. Whenever I upload any image in this picture library the thumbnail images are not displayed in thumbnail view.  Both the thumbnail and website images are created in folders(_t and _w).  After editing the item in picture view I am able to find that Both Preview field is not displaying Thumbnail and the Picture size column is also blank.

This is the same behavior in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

are you uploading images **programatically**,

if yes then it will **not generate** the thumbnails.

if you are not uploading it programatically, what are you getting on thumbnails.aspx view

please see the property of image, where Airbnb.jpg is my image.and when I hit below address explorer it shows me thumbnail.

```
http://localhost:40181/PublishingImages/_t/AirBnb_jpg.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am not Uploading it Programatically, second thing I can see that thumbnail as you said but in thumbnails view of picture library it is not showing  and when i click on that image instead of opening its property and image it is directly open in Browser wth URL as http://localhost:40181/PublishingImages/AirBnb_jpg.jpg

Comment: so what are you able to see in thumbnails view, is it showing blank or broken picture? if its broken we can understand where its pointing.

Comment: yes i have brokem picture like red X

Comment: aha..now you can get which location is it trying to get the picture from..let me know whats the location it is trying to get it?

Comment: it is getting my picture librayr name  and from there it is trying to get the image as thumbnail image

Comment: can you post the complete address to which it is pointing..like http://sps-3-sg0101-08:8888/PublishingImages/_t/demodude_png.jpg

Comment: this is the complete address generated after clicking on image http://localhost:999/CommTest%20Image%20Library/12312312.png

where 12312312.png is image

Comment: thats fine...but whats the address of thubmnail where its giving red X..right click on the red X and see whats the image URL..

Comment: I am sorry when I click on Image instead of showing red X it will show the Image in WEb image format with the Image url  given aboce. it does not provide the Edit form.aspx? like link and not showing any property like NAme , picture size and all that/

Comment: Its not the solution because it is possible to display thumbnails of images that are uploaded programatically

Answer (score 0):

Check the credentials used under the APPLICATION POOLS\IDENTITY tab.  The same thing happened to me just now and since this is an old server that does not get bounced too often, and we had changed the password for that account in the Identity tab, the information was in cached and the paged looked fine.  The moment we rebooted the box we were getting the "x".  We entered the new password and voila!  it worked.

Comment: Credentials doesn't play a role in thumbnail display